Having issues with Webhooks Gitea TLS certificate
I am facing some issue with Webhooks Gitea and Jenkins.
I have added a webhook which has this url -> https://my_jenkins_url/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=gitea-webhook.
Then I have Trigger On Push Events.
Branch it is Main.
So if I give Http it is coming this 404 error.
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>

And the POST request it is that.
Request URL: http://my_jenkins_url/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=gitea-webhook
Request method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
X-GitHub-Delivery: ba7cf69c-68b4-49c7-8b67-13db7a963de8
X-GitHub-Event: push
X-GitHub-Event-Type: push
X-Gitea-Delivery: ba7cf69c-68b4-49c7-8b67-13db7a963de8
X-Gitea-Event: push
X-Gitea-Event-Type: push
X-Gitea-Signature: 
X-Gogs-Delivery: ba7cf69c-68b4-49c7-8b67-13db7a963de8
X-Gogs-Event: push
X-Gogs-Event-Type: push
X-Gogs-Signature: 
X-Hub-Signature: sha1=
X-Hub-Signature-256: sha256=`

And if I give https it is coming this error.
Delivery: Post "https://my_jenkins_url/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=gitea-webhook": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match my_jenkins_url
But If I call directly this URL https://my_jenkins_url/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=gitea-webhook on the jenkins or browser it automatically starts a job on jenkins.
Same with the Postman I can send through Postman POST Request and triggers build job
The problem it is that Gitea it is triggering webhooks but then it is failling to start a job on jenkins.
I have tried to check the Gitea Servers on the Jenkins and they are all configured with HTTPS and there is everything all right.
In Jenkins: on the job settings page I set "Source Code Management" option to "Git", provided URL of repo (https://gitea-url.your.org/username/repo.git), and in "Poll triggers" section I checked "Poll SCM" option with no schedule defined.

Your browser and Gitea might be seeing different things because you are looking from different networks. Your browser is likely on the same corp network as your jenkins, but from outside of your corp network Gitea might see some sort of firewall or load balancer. Try the same jenkins url from your phone, on the cell network, not on Wi-Fi.

I cannot call the URL from my phone because the whole system that I am working it is in Virtual Machine.

Is your Gitea installed locally on the same network then?

I think yes don't know sure, I have only access as User with admin rights on both of them

You need to be sure :) Network connectivity between your Gitea and Jenkins is not a given.

Sorry to ask but how can I check it ?
I mean if they are on same network.

Ask your network admin. Or an SRE. See what IP the domain name for your Gitea resolves to and check if it's on your network.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
